# Show that $g(x)$ is identically $0$ on an interval of convergence

Tags: real-analysis

I came across this question in Stephen Abbott's *Understanding Analysis*, 2nd edition.

Let $g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_nx^n$ converge on $(-R,R)$, and assume $(x_n)\rightarrow0$ with $x_n\neq0$. If $g(x_n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, show that $g(x)$ must be identically zero on all of $(-R,R)$.

I believe that I need to use the fact that $g(x)$ is continuous on $(-R,R)$ by convergence. But I do not know exactly how this helps restrict the values of $g(x)$ to be $0$ on all of $(-R,R)$.

Comment: Hint: Consider the smallest $k$ such that $b_k\ne0$, then $g(x_n)$ is equivalent to $____$ hence...

Comment: @Did, I'm afraid I don't understand your hint. If I consider the smallest $k$ such that $b_k\neq 0$, how does that change what $g(x_n)$ is equivalent to?

Comment: Say $g(x)=5x^4+3x^6+$[some higher order terms], what is $g(x_n)$ equivalent to when $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @Did It is equivalent to $g(0)=0$ by continuity. But we already know that by assumption that $g(x_n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: No no, there is much more information in this: again, what is a simple equivalent of $g(x_n)$ when $n\to\infty$, under the hypothesis in my ptrevious comment?

Comment: You will see this as "uniqueness of holomorphic functions" when you learn complex analysis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Did's hint . . .

Suppose $g(x)$ is not identically $0$ on $(-R,R)$.

Then the coefficients$\;b_0,b_1,b_2,...\;$ are not all zero.

Let $k$ be the least nonnegative integer such that $b_k \ne 0$.

Then on $(-R,R)$, 
$$g(x) = x^kf(x)$$
where
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty}b_nx^{n-k}$$

Since $g$ converges on $(-R,R)$, so does $f$, hence $f$ is continuous on $(-R,R)$.

For all $n$,
\begin{align*}
&g(x_n) = 0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(x_n)^kf(x_n) = 0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&f(x_n) = 0&&\text{[since $x_n \ne 0$]}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
But then since $f$ is continuous on $(-R,R)$,
$$b_k = f(0) = \lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 0 = 0$$
contradiction.